# Removing php with htaccess does not work on subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to remove .php extension from URL with ataccess file. The code I am using is this:

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

But, when I include this code in ataccess file, my subdomain, m.mydomain.com, gives me 404 error. How can I remove .php from any file in the main domain and sub domains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put your .htaccess file also in the root of your subdomain.